# elegant Java class downcast

Tags: java, casting

Let A be a superclass of AB and AC. Given a method:

```
public void handleStuff(A someObject) {
  if(someObject instanceof AB){ 
     ((AB)someObject).someABFunction();
  } else if(someObject instanceof AC) {
     ((AC)someObject).someACFunction();
  }
}
```

I don't like the double checking/casting operation here; is there any other way to code this without first checking for a type and then casting? I know I could do it with two overloaded functions that take AB or AC as parameters, but I was looking for less code, not more :-) Something like:

```
public void handleStuff(A someObject) {
  if(someObject instanceof AB){ 
     someObject.someABFunction(); // it is already clear that this is AB
  } else if(someObject instanceof AC) {
     someObject.someACFunction(); // it is already clear that this is AC
  }
}
```

Comment: You could add an abstract method to A that is implemented differently in AB and AC.

Comment: Apart from using polymorphism which circumvents the problem entirely, since Java 14 you can use instanceof pattern matching: https://www.baeldung.com/java-pattern-matching-instanceof. In short, `if (someObject instanceOf AB ab) { ab.someAbFunction() }`.

Comment: @PetrJaneček: it's only been a preview feature in Java 14. Java 16 made it a final, regular feature.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On Java 16 and newer, you can use pattern matching to avoid the cast. Like this:

```
public void handleStuff(A someObject) {
  if (someObject instanceof AB ab) { 
     ab.someABFunction();
  } else if (someObject instanceof AC ac) {
     ac.someACFunction();
  }
}
```

On Java 17 and newer, you can enable the preview feature for pattern matching in switch-expressions to shorten it further. With that feature, you can do this:

```
public void handleStuff(A someObject) {
  switch (someObject) {
    case AB ab -> ab.someABFunction();
    case AC ac -> ac.someACFunction();
    default -> {}
  }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't compiler force to handle the default case in switch ?

Comment: Note that those are two slightly different features. The first one (pattern matching for instanceof) is already final since Java 16, so no need to enable preview features at all. The second one (pattern matching for switch) is still preview in Java 17 (as well as in Java 20).

Comment: @S.D. Right, fixed.

Comment: Exactly what I was searching for, thanks a lot!